# React | Pass Redux state with create selector and hide menu item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

In the React Component that handles the Sidebar, we have the `Menu Items`, as `modules`. I want to pass a specific state from Redux, and in the case of false hide a specific item.
I did it but with passing the state as Props with `componentWillRecieveProps`. But I need to do it specifically with `createSelector` from `reselect`, as componentWillRecieveProps is gonna be deprecated and we are starting to using reselect more and more.

Problem is I have no idea how to do that. The reselect docs are more confusing than helping. **So can you help a little?**

**Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { isRouteActive } from './location';

class ModuleNavigation extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    modules: PropTypes.array,
    user: PropTypes.object,
    currentRoute: PropTypes.string,
    isMinimized: PropTypes.bool,
    isItAvailable: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.topNavRef = React.createRef();
    this.bottomNavRef = React.createRef();
    this.moduleNavRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateArrows();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateArrows();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateArrows);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateArrows);
  }

  onToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  getRefId = (index) => {
    if (index === 0) return this.topNavRef;
    if (this.props.modules && index === this.props.modules.length - 1) return this.bottomNavRef;

    return null;
  }

  renderGroup = (group, index, user, currentRoute, isMinimized) => (
    <ul ref={this.getRefId(index)} key={group.name} className="module-navigation-group nav">
      {
        <li className={classNames('mt-10 mb-10 module-navigation-group-separator', { hidden: index === 0 })} />
      }
      {group.children
        .filter(mod =>
          mod.route && (!mod.permissions || userHasPermission(user, mod.permissions)))
        .map(mod =>
          (<li key={mod.name} className={classNames('module-navigation-group-item', { active: isRouteActive(currentRoute, mod.route) })}>
            <a href={(mod.parentApp ? '#' : '') + mod.route} target={mod.target} title={mod.name}>
              <i className={`fa ${mod.classNames} module-navigation-group-item-icon`} />
              {!isMinimized && <span className="hidden-xs hidden-sm ml-15 module-navigation-group-item-label">{mod.name}</span>}
            </a>
          </li>))}
    </ul>
  )

  render() {
    const {
      modules,
      currentRoute,
      user,
      isItAvailable,
    } = this.props;

    if (!user || !modules || !modules.length) return null;

    return (
      <div className={classNames('module-navigation-wrapper', { 'is-minimized': isMinimized })}>
        <div ref={this.moduleNavRef} isZKAvailable={isZKAvailable} className="module-navigation">
          {
            modules.map((group, index) =>
              this.renderGroup(group, index, user, currentRoute, isMinimized))
          }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModuleNavigation;
```

I want to pass the boolean `isItAvailable` to menu-items called `modules` here, and check the children of modules, for a specific one. If `isItAvaialable =false` dont show it

Comment: FYI, this is the original Component without my `componentWillRecieveProps` implementation.

Comment: I also removed a lot of imports and JSX regarding them to clear things up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need a small refactoring to your class component, so that you can wrap the component with the `connect` hoc and get **state values and inject them as props**.

### In your class component you make these changes, in order to get the `isAvailable` as prop, e.g. `this.props.isAvailable`:

```
// import connect hoc from react-redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// import your selector from e.g. selectors.js, on the top
import {getIsAvailable} from './selectors'


// bottom, out of the class create the mapStateToProps function,
// in order to get state values and inject them as props to the component
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAvailable: getIsAvailable(state),
  }
}

// you export your component wrapped with the connect hoc, like so
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ModuleNavigation)
```

### Into your selectors file, you import `reselect` and use `CreateSelecto` like so:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

// get the local state data.
// you are gonna change the structure based on yours
const getLocalState = state => state.data

// here with creteSelector:
// 1. call the localstate and return the data
// 2. get the data as param of an arrow func and 
// make whatever we like with the data (calcs, checks etc)
// and finally return the data we need.
export const getIsAvailable = createSelector(
  getLocalState,
  data => data.isAvailable || false
)
```

Thats it. i hope it helps.

Comment: I have a question. What is the `getIsAvaialable`? Redux sends an entire object for this specific action, with all the app info. The question is. What do I pass in the selector..

Comment: I m not sure that i got exactly your issue. I made a simple redux example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j2r4l03nvw, 
 that gets state properties and injects them into 'MyComponent', with 'createSelector'.

Comment: Thank you. I got the gist of it. I used a little different approach. But your example was very useful.